# django/nginx/gunicorn время ответа сервера

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

Добрый день!

Development server:

- FreeBSD 10.0-RELEASE (2*CPU 48RAM)
- Django 1.6
- Gunicorn 19.2.1 (workers numCPUs*2+1)
- Nginx 1.6.2

Тест web-проекта показывает на слишком большое значение "Время ответа сервера". На легкой странице из серии "О компании" получаю ≈850мс, эталон <= 200мс.

Работая с проектом на локальном ПК в PyCharm время ответа сервера на данной странице ≈85мс.

Коллеги, подскажите куда копать/как лечить?

Comment: я использую uwsgi и в похожих условиях имею 10 миллисекунд на генерирование страницы весом в 10 килобайт

Comment: У меня проблема была из-за того, что gunicorn max_requests =1
Тестирую сервер на max_requests =500, время ответа ≈300мс.